# Dynamically load table using dropdown list Jquery .ajax() method

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have learnt about jQuery through the other questions that are posted here that are somewhat similar. My problem is that I have a workable drop-down list that lists the 7 continents in the world. Once a continent is selected it should show the countries that below to the continent. This is where I am having trouble:

**jsonTest.html**

```
<html>
<head><title>JSON jQuery AJAX</title></head>
<body>

<div>Users </div>
<select id="sel_user">

</select>



<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="myscript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**getCountry.php**

```
<?php
require_once('pdoDB.class.php');
$countryID = $_POST['countryID'];
//$countryID = "EU";
//echo $countryID;
$db = pdoDB::getConnection();
$country_arr = array();
 $sql = "SELECT Name,SurfaceArea 
            FROM w_country WHERE Continent='".$countryID."'";
$stmt = $db->query($sql); 
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $name = $row['Name'];
    $surfaceArea = $row['SurfaceArea'];

    $country_arr[] = array("name" => $name, "surfaceArea" => $surfaceArea);
    echo json_encode($country_arr);

  }

?>
```

**myscript.js**

```
$(document).ready( function() {
 $.getJSON( "ajax1.php", function(obj) { 
  $.each(obj, function(key, value) { 

        // append("<li>"+ value.Name +  
                  //   "</li></br>");
         $("#sel_user").
         append("<option value='"+value.Id+"'>"
                       +value.Name+"</option>");

  });
 });
  $("#sel_user").change(function(){
        var Id = $(this).val();
        alert(Id);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'getCountry.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {countryID:Id},
            dataType: 'json',
            success:function(response){

                var len = response.length;
                $("#sel_user").empty();
                for( var i = 0; i<len; i++){
                    var id = response[i]['name'];
                    var area = response[i]['surfaceArea'];

                    $("#sel_user").append("<li>heheh</li>");



 }
            }
        });
    });

});
```

I am able to show the continents on the drop-down list but unable to pass the country ID to the php page to show the country details.

Comment: Why are you unable to pass the ID? What happens instead when you run your script?

Comment: i can see my dropdownlist and the alert pops up to display the continent ID. However there should be a table to display the country name and surface area for all the countries in the particular continent.i have even tested the getcountry.php on its own and it shows the list of countries in a particular continent very nicely.

Comment: Please edit the question to contain all relevant information. Have you checked whether the AJAX call returns the raw data you expect?

Comment: i dont know how to check

Comment: You could set breakpoints in your code to monitor the AJAX response and the handling, you could add `console.log` to the `success` callback,....

Comment: i put console.log(response); then i notices a long list of country names in the console. but it does want to come out in the browser

Comment: its coming out in the console. but lots of repetitive data

Comment: Did you try checking whatever that loop handling your AJAX data really does? Why does it append a static list element `<li>` to a `<select>`?